# unix compare lists of file names

Tags: unix, while-loop, compare, sftp, exists

I believe similar questions have been answered on SO before.  I cant find any that seem to match to my particular situation, though I am sure many others have faced this scenario.

In an FTP session on Red Hat I have produced a list of file names that reside on the server currently.  The list contains the file names and only the file names.  Call this file1.  Perhaps it contains something like:

```
513569430_EDIP000754535900_MFC_20190618032554.txt
blah.txt
duh.txt
```

Then I have downloaded the files and produced a list of successfully downloaded files.  As well, this list contains the file names and only the file names.  Call this file2.  Perhaps it contains something like:

```
loadFile.dat
513569430_EDIP000754535900_MFC_20190618032554.txt
localoutfile.log
```

Now I want to loop through the names in file1 and check if they exist in file2.  If exists I will go back to FTP server and delete the file from server.

I have looked at while loops and comm and test command, but I just cant seem to crack the code.  I expect there are many ways to achieve this task.  Any suggestions out there or working references?

My area of trouble is really not the looping itself but rather the comparing of contents between 2 files.

Comment: `sort file1 file1 file2 | uniq -c | sed '/^ *3 /!d;s///;s/[^A-Za-z0-9]/\\&/g;s/^/rm /' > sftp-batch-cmds`

Comment: bash: `comm -1 -2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | ...`

Comment: By all accounts' comm -12 file1 file2' should give me the 1 record that matches but it returns nothing.

Comment: Could be line-ending (`\r\n` vs `\n` vs `\r`) differences. Try viewing with `grep 513569430_EDIP000754535900_MFC_20190618032554 file? | od -c`

Comment: Right on.  file1 ends with \r \n and file2 end with \n only.  Any hot tips on dealing with this one?

Comment: `dos2unix file1` will strip out the `\n`. If your system doesn't have that, there are other ways to do it. Try searching `[bash] dos2unix sed`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`comm -1 -2 file1 file2` returns just the lines that are identical in both files. This can be used as the basis of a batch command file for `sftp`.

From the comments to the question, it seems that line-endings differ for the two files. This can be fixed in various ways, simplest probably being with `tr`. `comm` understands `-` as a filename to mean "read from stdin".

For example:

```
tr -d '\r` file1 | comm -1 -2 - file2
```

If file1 or file2 are not sorted, this must be corrected for `comm` to operate properly. With bash, this could be:

```
comm -1 -2 <( sort file1 | tr -d '\r' ) <( sort file2 )
```

With shells that don't understand the `<( ... )` syntax, temporary files may be used explicitly.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the advice @jhnc.

After giving this some deeper consideration and conversation, I realized that I don't even need to do this comparison.  After I download the files I just need to produce the list of successful downloads.  Then I can go and delete from server based on list of successful downloads.

However, I am still interested to know how to compare with the `'\r \n'` vs `'\n'` line ending situation